# JS - apostrophe - wont get replaced

Tags: javascript, string

I'm having this problem with the apostrophe ("'") in JS. I'm using the encodeURIComponent() to encode this and then replace the (') with (%27) as follows.

var request = encodeURIComponent(requestString).replace("'", "%27");

But if the apostrophe is with a bracket, the apostrophe wont get replaced.

ex: (")'")
    ("')")
    ("('")

Even when the apostrophe is followed by a numeric number it wont get replaced.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Nilushi

Answer (score 3):

[`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method accepts a string or regular expression as its first parameter. When a string is passed as the first parameter, only the first match is replaced:

```
"'''''".replace("'", "%27"); // "%27''''"
```

You should use a regular expression instead along with the `g` flag; which replaces ALL matches:

```
"'''''".replace(/'/g, "%27"); // "%27%27%27%27%27"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `/g` global modifier:

```
var request = encodeURIComponent(requestString).replace(/'/g, "%27");
```

**Example:**

```
var str = "(''')";
var request = encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/'/g, "%27");
console.log(request); // (%27%27%27)
```